# Шифр Цезаря для бинарных данных

Tags: c#, криптография, алгоритм, шифрование

Здравствуйте, уважаемые, столкнулся с интересной задачкой и впал в ступор. Собственно, имеется бинарный файл зашифрованный алгоритмом Цезаря. Вроде бы ничего сложного, но вот с функцией расшифровки при реализации возникли проблемы, и собственно встал в ступор.

Собственно, стандартный Цезарь то реализуется достаточно просто, но здесь даже идей нет как реализовать. Если есть люди разбирающиеся в криптографии, прошу помочь, даже примерным алгоритмом действий.

Comment: @iPro, сдвигать буквы будете или биты?

Comment: Биты естественно, поэтому и затормозил немного, без понятия по какому правилу их сдвигать

Comment: @iPro, в смысле по какому правилу? Вы знаете на сколько сдвиг сделан? Сдвиги в c# реализуются при помощи операторов >> и << http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xt18et0d.aspx

Если проблема именно с циклическим сдвигом, то тут есть пример: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread31976.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А зачем сдвигать биты? это уже не шифр Цезаря будет. Я бы делал бы так, как алгоритм приписывает.

Шифрование

```
a = (a + c) % 256;
```

дешифровка

```
a = (a + 256 - c) % 256;
```

где `a` - шифруемый байт, а `с` - ключ для сдвига.